# How much Redis is scalable as a time-series database

Tags: redis, time-series

I am using Redis as time series database. I am importing mysql data into Redis by reforming data in the format of score and value in order to fit data into sorted set. I have 26 tables and at some point of time data, they can extend to  100 million records for every table.

- Is it okay to store that much of data into Redis as Redis stores data in memory?
- Is there an chance of Redis crash? If yes how often it will crash?
- Is it okay to use Redis for my task?

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/articles/redis-time-series

Comment: as long as the data will fit in memory, and you are using a stable version, redis will not crash. or at least the probability is very very low. I've been using redis in production for 7 years and never had a crash.

Comment: Hey, redis is pretty stable and with availability of memory works really fine. However, no one can guarantee that it will never crash just like any other system.    Amount of Data is not an issue

Comment: Thanks @DkGeek and @ Not_a_Golfer  for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself how you intend to query your data. Will you access single values or do scans?

Depending on your answers, a more specialized solution might be a better fit for your problem:

Warp 10 (disclaimer: I help build it)
InfluxDB
KairosDB
OpenTSDB